# Highlight cell value on doubleclick for copy

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have a jqGrid. I would like to highlight a particular cell from a row, ondbClickRow. This would make the task of copying the value of a cell onto clipboard, easy for users. Can someone guide me on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it would be possible, but you should probably switch off row selection to see highlighting immediately. So the code will be about the following:

```
beforeSelectRow: function () {
    return false;
},
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass('ui-state-highlight');
}
```

As the result you can have the grid like

[image]

see the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HighlightOnDoubleClick.htm)

**UPDATED**: If you need **select** the text in the grid cell you can use the idea described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/315935). In case of usage inside of jqGrid the code could be the following:

```
var selectText = function (element) {
    var doc = element.ownerDocument, selection, range;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.setBaseAndExtent) { // webkit
            selection.setBaseAndExtent(element, 0, element, 1);
        } else { // moz, opera
            range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
};

$("#list").jqGrid({
    // ... jqGrid options
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        selectText(e.target);
    }
});
```

The [next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectTextOnDoubleClick.htm) demonstrate this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Oleg. This is pretty close to what I wanted. In the "Date" column from your example, is there any way to get the entire date selected and not get delimited by - or /? The column my users would be selecting is URL.

Comment: @Jai: I don't understand what you mean. How you can see on the picture above the whole cell will be highlighted.

Comment: I tried posting an image but failed to do so. Please look at the data 01-Oct-2007 in the following screenshot. [screenshot](https://picasaweb.google.com/115278692335129964011/Stackof#5681191684714414994) I am looking to do a selection for copy instead of just highlighting the cell

Comment: @Jai: There are LARGE difference between highlighting of the cell and selection of the text in the cell! I created new demo for you (see the **UPDATED** part of my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much. I always find your contributions to stackoverflow very valuable