# How can I highlight an cell's entire contents in jqgrid when clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, click, highlight

I have a jqgrid table that has a username and password column, and if I could add automatic selection of a cell's entire contents when the cell is clicked, that would be of great benefit to those who use the table for their work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#theTable").jqGrid({
            [...]
            colNames:[[...],'Username', 'Password',[...],
            colModel:[
                [...]
                {name: 'username', index: 'username', width: 110, sorttype: 'text', cellattr: function () {return 'class="selectcell"'}},
                {name: 'password', index: 'password', width: 110, sorttype: 'text', cellattr: function () {return 'class="selectcell"'}},
                [...]
            ],
        });
```

Then later on...

```
$(".selectcell").click(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

I took that `$.click()` from code that automatically selects an entire textbox whenever it is clicked on. It functions perfectly there, but it isn't working as is. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't use any editing of the grid. You can add `cellEdit: true` in the situation. The option allowed to *edit* cells of columns which have `editing: true` property. Cell editing have one more important feature. It highlight the cell of all non-editable columns. Because all columns are not editable in your case then you will have the feature highlighting of cells just by adding `cellEdit: true` option.

If you do need to select **the text** in the cell then I would recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334227/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectTextOnDoubleClick.htm)) which demonstrates how to select the text inside of clicked cell on double-click.

Comment: It looks like the second example in your old answer is what I need! :) I'll be back after testing.

Comment: @ZAD-Man: Have you finished your tests?

Comment: I had another project that came up that has priority over this one, sorry. Not sure when I'll be back to it.